# Input of second Scanner object mismatches the type..?

Tags: java

I'm writing this small program where user digit two dates, the program calculates the time between the first and the second date.

```
    String amPm1, amPm2, temp;
    int ore1, ore2, minuti1, minuti2, secondi1, secondi2, ore, minuti, secondi;
    
    Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    input1.useDelimiter(":");

    System.out.println("Inserisci due orari separati e ti dirò la differenza di tempo chew intercorre tra i due.");
    System.out.println("L'orario deve essere scritto secondo il seguente formato HH:MM:SS AM/PM");
    System.out.println("Primo orario: ");
    
    ore1 = input1.nextInt();
    minuti1 = input1.nextInt();
    temp = input1.nextLine();
    secondi1 = Integer.parseInt(temp.substring(1, (temp.length() - 3)));
    amPm1 = temp.substring((temp.length() - 2), temp.length());
    
    System.out.printf("ore: %d\nminuti: %d\nsecondi: %d\n%s\n", ore1, minuti1, secondi1, amPm1);
    
    if ((ore1 > 12 || ore1 < 1) || (minuti1 > 59 || minuti1 < 0) || (secondi1 > 59 || secondi1 < 0) || 
            !(amPm1.equalsIgnoreCase("AM")) || (amPm1.equalsIgnoreCase("PM")))
        System.out.println("Errore - l'orario inserito non è valido.");

    
    System.out.println("Secondo orario: ");
    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    input2.useDelimiter(":");
    ore2 = input2.nextInt();
    System.out.println(ore2);
    minuti2 = input2.nextInt();
    System.out.println(minuti2);
    temp = input2.nextLine();
    System.out.println(temp);
    secondi2 = Integer.parseInt(temp.substring(1, (temp.length() - 3)));
    System.out.println(secondi2);
    amPm2 = temp.substring((temp.length() - 2), temp.length());
    System.out.println(amPm2);
```

When I digit the second date, then the second Scanner object returns an InputMismatchException:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

exactly at this line:
ore2 = input2.nextInt();

Comment: You shouldn't be mixing nextLine and other nextXYZ (eg nextInt) methods; the interactions between the methods get confusing and complex and tend to introduce errors. Just do a nextLine and use regex or something to parse out the bits you need.

Comment: also why are you creating a second scanner?

Comment: I tried with Integer.parseInt(input1.nextLine()), and removed the second Scanner. As result it return a NumberFormatException error.

Comment: More, if I don't use the parse, just remove the second Scanner, the program lets me digit the first date, then prints the line with "Secondo orario", and returns the InputMismatchException..

Comment: Re your first comment, you should be parsing the _string_ from nextLine() and then using regex to pull out the bits you need. or at least verifying the format before trying to pass it blindly to a parseInt.

Comment: You keep getting input mismatches because you're trying to read integers from an input stream where the next token is _not_ an integer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really getting it. I changed "ore2" from an int type to a String type and it works with next(). But I can't parse it as an integer anymore.but what I don't get is, why in the first scanner if I digit "12:24:35 am" it takes "12" as an integer, but in the second scanner (I used the same code as first scanner) if I digit "12:24:35 am" it doesn't let me save 12 as an integer but as a string

Comment: Solved in this way, but still didn't get what you meant (my bad) ...   
temp = input1.nextLine();
  String[] splitted = temp.split(":");
  ore1 = Integer.parseInt(splitted[0]);
  minuti1 = Integer.parseInt(splitted[1]);
  secondi1 = Integer.parseInt(splitted[2].substring(0, (splitted[2].length() - 3)));
  amPm1 = splitted[2].substring((splitted[2].length() - 2), splitted[2].length());